# how to count array values without 0

Tags: php

```
$q1=15;
$q2=12;
$q3=23;
$q4=0;
$q5=0;


$count = array ($q1, $q2, $q3, $q4, $q5);
echo count($count);
```

This get the count as 5;
But I want to count without zeros. How to do that?
I want to count = 3

Comment: Read about [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php).

Comment: From the way you built your array, there's no `0` in it, just sayin'

Comment: Lost count of the number of times I've had to post a link to the PHP Strings page ... http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php ... `"` is **not** the same as `'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use array_filter() and it is built in function so no worry about it.

```
echo count(array_filter($your_array));
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php

```
<?php
$q1=15;
$q2=12;
$q3=23;
$q4=0;
$q5=0;

$count = array ($q1, $q2, $q3, $q4, $q5);
echo count(array_filter($count));
```

if you want to check your final array value then use this code also

```
$count = array($q1, $q2, $q3, $q4, $q5);
$final_arr = array_filter($count);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($final_arr);
```

you can use this code also which remove all 0 value

```
$count = array($q1, $q2, $q3, $q4, $q5);
function nonzero($var)
{
 return ($var > 0);
}

$arr = array_filter($count, "nonzero");
echo count($arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your array contains strings "$q1", "$q2", "$q3" and so on,
if you want to store their values you dont even need to use quotes, or if you want to you can use double quotes ("").

You can count them manually like this:

```
$count = 0;
foreach($array as $el){
    if($el != 0){
        $count++;
    }
}
```

or use `array_filter()` built in function.

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong way to declare array becouse you are passing strings to array. You should add variables without ''. If you want to count without zero you could write simple foreach loop.

```
 $countWithoutZeros=0;
foreach($count as $number){ if($number!=0){$countWithoutZeros++}}
```

Answer (score 0):

`array_filter()` is your friend.

```
$q1=15;
$q2=12;
$q3=23;
$q4=0;
$q5=0;

$a = array ($q1, $q2, $q3, $q4, $q5);

# Method 1
$b = array_filter($a, function($v){return $v !== 0;});
var_dump($b);
echo "<p>Count: ".count($b)."</p>";

# Method 2
$b = array_filter($a);
var_dump($b);
echo "<p>Count: ".count($b)."</p>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$q1=15;
$q2=12;
$q3=23;
$q4=0;
$q5=0;


$count = array ($q1, $q2, $q3, $q4, $q5);
$count = array_filter($count);
echo count($count);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can count using the filter function as @axiac is commented

```
function nonzero($var){ 
    return ($var > 0); } 


$arr = array_filter($array, "nonzero"); 
echo count($arr);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

tyr this :D

```
 $c=0;
 $count = array ('$q1','$q2','$q3','$q4','$q5');
for(i=0;i<count($count);i++){
  if(!$count[$i]==0){ 
      $c++}
  else{ continue; }
  }
 echo $c;
```

also read about  array_filter()